# Haskell - Trying to have output type a using Prelude.read to also work for String

Tags: haskell, types

I was making a small program that I would never put on github or distribute and I noticed a pattern of asking stuff on the command line and getting the answer and using it. So I wanted to make this pattern into a function.

```
askQuestion :: (Read a) => String -> IO a
askQuestion q = do
     putStrLn q
     read <$> getLine
```

Of course this kind of function isn't particularly safe as it throws an error when the answer given by the user isn't able to be parsed. Which is why readMaybe or readEither is recommended. But as I am the only user of the code I don't mind as I know what is needed for my program.

After this I thought of another pattern my code used a lot which is asking the user to choose between two options, after which my program branches depending on the answer. I also made a function for this.

```
askOption :: String -> String -> String -> IO a -> IO a -> IO a
askOption q a1 a2 ac1 ac2 = do
   putStrLn q
   ans <- getLine
   if a1 == ans
    then ac1
    else if a2 == ans
          then ac2
          else error $ "Not one of the options for question " ++ q
```

This code worked perfectly for what I wanted it and made my main functions look pretty clean. But when I noticed

```
putStrLn q
ans <- getLine
```

in my askOption function I wanted to replace that block with the askQuestion function.

This is where my problem lies, apparently read can't parse a string to a string. Now I guess it was pretty obvious that you can't expect that but I hoped read would just forward the string without doing anything to it.

What I wanted to know is if it was possible to have a system where if read notices it's a string it just passes it through. I want to keep the clean type IO a and not have to refactor my code to use IO Maybe a or IO Either String a. I know I can handle the error and then in the handle use getLine to get the answer. But this would require me to type the answer twice everytime. Once to fail and once when it succeeds.

```
ans <- handle (\(SomeException e) -> putStrLn "Answer again" >> getLine) $ askQuestion "Give Input"
```

This would keep the type I wanted but be a pain for the actual program.

The other option I thought of was checking if ans was a string in the askQuestion function and if it was return the string and else perform the read. But this would break the IO a type as IO String isn't equal to IO a.

Summary: is there a way to make the type signature of askQuestion remain IO a while passing answers that aren't able to be read back as Strings. I know using readEither/readMaybe is preferred in real practice but I just wanted to do this for fun.

Comment: can't it? :) `GHCi> read "\"1\"" :: String` ==>
 `"1"`

Comment: @WillNess You're right, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with your existing `askQuestion` function, because its use of `read` is hardwired into it, and you don't wish to use `read` in this case. To make this function more flexible, extract a parameter from it:

```
askQuestion' :: (String -> a) -> String -> IO a
askQuestion' parse prompt = do
  putStrLn prompt 
  parse <$> getLine
```

Then your original `askQuestion` can be defined as:

```
askQuestion :: (Read a) => String -> IO a
askQuestion = askQuestion' read
```

and your new `askOption` can use the more flexible function:

```
askOption :: String -> String -> String -> IO a -> IO a -> IO a
askOption q a1 a2 ac1 ac2 = do
   ans <- askQuestion' id q
   if a1 == ans
    then ac1
    else if a2 == ans
          then ac2
          else error $ "Not one of the options for question " ++ q
```

Comment: Yes this is perfect. I hadn't thought about parameterizing the read function. Thank you! I'll accept this as an answer when possible.

Comment: @XanderDeJaegere This is a good suggestion, but do note that this isn't quite "a way to make the type signature of askQuestion remain IO a while passing answers that aren't able to be read back as Strings"; the code that calls `askQuestion` has to fix exactly what type it's expecting ahead of time, this won't allow the type returned to depend on what the user types after the prompt.

Comment: @Ben I may have worded my question wrong then. This solution doesn't make the askQuestion function pass Strings back when it isn't able to parse the answer given by the prompt. It's the same as my function. If there is way to do this I'd like to hear it. But it does provide a good answer for what I actually wanted to do. Which is use the askQuestion pattern for strings and everything else. As I know what I'm expecting for answers I can choose the correct one.

Comment: @XanderDeJaegere All good! I just wanted to make sure you understood that, but it sounds like you already do. (It's a fairly common misconception for people to have about `read` that they might be able to use it to return different types based on what is in the data)